# Running applications in Tomcat without unpacking WAR

Tags: tomcat, java

I want to set to false attribute **unpackWARs** in Tomcat host configuration file.

Does running unpacked WAR affects an application performance?

Comment: You might want to update your tags to include windows as WAR files are Windows-specific (Windows only).

Comment: It cannot be so. I deploy WAR to Linux server.

Comment: @Richard T: What makes you believe WAR files are Windows-specific? WAR (Web Application Archive) is a standard format defined by Sun Microsystems for Java applications. It is cross-platform, and used on all platforms Java runs on.

Comment: Doah! What _was_ I thinking? -shrug- (At the moment I can't quite recall what file type I was thinking of.) Ah well, I'll blame it on lack of coffee at the time! -wink-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run a setup like this for one of our applications.  No real performance problems other than the Java overhead to begin with.  Just be careful about dynamic files, they tend to be a pain when you keep it all packed together since WAR files and dynamic files don't work well together.

Overall nothing on my end.  Our application is a Supply Chain Management system, runs on a web server with a DB backend, accessed 20 hours a day from suppliers around the world, average user load is 20-30 per hour with lots of updates and requests.